# Java: Can I send Thread.wait() and Thread.notify() on the PipedOutputStream?

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe, wait, notify

Can I send from the Producer Thread on PipedOutputStream the wait()-Signal to the Receiver Thread, so that the Receiver "sleeps" until the notify()-Singal comes from the Producer Thread?

The Task is to check the InputStream in Receiver as soon as the Producer puts bytes on the Stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon issuing a `read` call in the receiving thread, the "receiver" will be in "sleep" mode (also called "blocked") until one of the following happens:

1. The "sender" closed the stream.
2. The thread, in which the "receiver" runs, is interrupted.
3. The "sender" sends something down the stream.

These are the only ways you can control the "receiver"'s behaviour.

If you think you must be able to pass signals, then you're most likely doing something wrong.

Comment: The best option would of course the Thread to interrupt and later restart it. But the task said that the Thread must start in the main and are not terminated.

Comment: So the only option which would be conceivable for me is to check the InputStream constantly for new inputs. Or?

Comment: @user3302074 no, you don't have to. All you need to do is just call the `read` method. The `read` method blocks until input is received.

Comment: But I have one query. I have the Pipe linked with ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream. When I set the Receiver Thread as no deamon then I get an EOFException. When I set the Receiver Thread as deamon then I get no Exceptions but I must bind in an sleep time so that all object are really written.